# Difference between Simulink vector / signal types

Tags: vector, signals, simulink

There appear to be 2 column vectors in Simulink (2013b). The following works without error:

[image]

However, swapping the inputs causes an error. The only way I was able to make it work was to add a reshape block. As you can see, the signal changes from a 105 to a [105, 1]:

[image]

So my question is, what is the difference between the 105 and [105, 1] signal types?

Comment: If the first input is a constant with 1:105, and treat as 1D is checked, and the second input is a constant with 1:105, and treat as 1D is unchecked, then the second multiplication (without the Reshape) works for me.